# table() output to a data frame with the column names

Tags: r

```
# dput(df)
structure(list(p = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L), q1 = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L), q2 = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L), q3 = c(7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L), q4 = c(3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

| p | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 | 8 | 7 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 7 |

```
d = NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  column<-names(df[i])
  o<-table(df[,i],df$product)
  names(dimnames(o)) <- c(column)
  print(o)
  d<-rbind(d,as.data.frame.matrix(o))
}
```

i am trying to loop through q1,q2 and so on to get a table with column name and then export it into a dataframe. I have tried various method but i am not able to get what i want.
so this is the output which i want but when made to a dataframe the column name is not there.

```
 Q22  1  2  3  4
  1  0  3  2  5
  2  4  3  7 18
  3 10 17 19 25
  4 44 30 44 33
  5 40 20 42 30
```

Is there any way to proceed through this problem? Thank you in advance.

---

Data

```r
# dput(df)
structure(list(p = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L), q1 = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L), q2 = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L), q3 = c(7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L), q4 = c(3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: ```dput``` your dataframe to make it reproducible.

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate on that.

Comment: Mistcoder, I suggested an edit to your question to add the output of `dput(df)`. This output is an unambiguous way to pass data through questions; while not the only way, there can be ambiguity when copying (say) the rendering of a frame on the R console, especially when there are non-trivial classes and/or embedded spaces. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: Can you add values for `product` to your `dput` output?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-p, names_to = "Q", values_to = "V") %>%
  group_by(p, Q, V) %>%
  tally() %>%
  pivot_wider(p:Q, names_from = "V", values_from = "n", values_fill = list(n=0L)) %>%
  select(p, Q, sort(colnames(.))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 x 10
#        p Q       `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`
#    <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1 q1        0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
#  2     1 q2        0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
#  3     1 q3        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
#  4     1 q4        0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#  5     2 q1        0     0     0     2     0     0     0     0
#  6     2 q2        0     0     0     0     2     0     0     0
#  7     2 q3        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2
#  8     2 q4        0     0     0     0     0     2     0     0
#  9     3 q1        0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0
# 10     3 q2        0     0     0     0     0     2     0     0
# 11     3 q3        0     0     0     0     0     2     0     0
# 12     3 q4        0     0     0     0     0     0     2     0
# 13     4 q1        1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 14     4 q2        0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
# 15     4 q3        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
# 16     4 q4        0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but have gotten the table of my choice but converting them into dataframe with column name is where i have trouble

Comment: I know you want things per-question, I wonder if this new answer meets your needs. If not, please update your expected output given the sample data you've provided. (This includes updating your code, since for example `df$product` is not found.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe through this approach actually, also i wanted to know if it was possible to get the percentage. Like % of 4's in q1.

Comment: None of your sample data has more than one distinct number per row, so all of these will be `100`. Try adding `%>% mutate(rowsum = rowSums(subset(., select=-c(p,Q)))) %>% mutate(across(-c(p,Q), ~ 100 * . / rowsum))`

Answer (score 0):

To get them all into one dataframe you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

purrr::imap_dfr(df, ~table(.)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_all(~tidyr::replace_na(., 0)) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c(names(df)))

  p q1 q2 q3 q4
1 1  0  0  0  0
2 2  1  0  0  0
3 2  0  0  0  1
4 1  3  0  0  0
5 0  2  1  0  0
6 0  0  2  0  1
7 0  0  2  4  2
8 0  0  1  0  2
9 0  0  0  2  0
```

If you want this to work with the subset of columns that starts with "q" then you can change `df` to `dplyr::select(df, starts_with("q"))`.